# Type accepting any collection

Tags: java

I have collection of `Set` and `List` so how can call a function who accept any type of collection ?

```
Set<X> myset = ...;
myfunction(myset);

List<X> mylist = ...;
myfunction(mylist);

myfunction(T collection){
}
```

So what would be the type of T ?

Comment: `Collection` is a *super* interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection`. `List` and `Set` interfaces extends `Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

Both `Set` and `List` extend [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using generics, T is simply a `Collection`:

```
void myfunction(Collection collection)
```

If you are, you could use `T extends Collection`

```
<T extends Collection> void myfunction(T collection)
```